# Duplicate class androidx

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to add a Bottom Navigation Activity to my project in android studio but when i run the project I get an error

Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy found in modules lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1) and lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1)
Duplicate class androidx.lifecycle.ViewTreeViewModelKt found in modules lifecycle-viewmodel-2.5.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.5.1) and lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx-2.3.1-runtime (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1)

I tried adding "android.enableJetifier=true" to gradle.properties file but it still gave me the same error.